# Where does my horse go after I'm arrested in Dragonsreach?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Where does my horse go after I'm arrested in Dragonsreach? I've looked everywhere within reason and can't find my horse. I was riding it when arrested and it wasn't stolen, any help? I cheked the stables were i had bought him and near buildings, the horse was alive when i was arrrested becouse i was riding him.

......After traveling to winterhold on foot i found my horse just standing there... it was the first time i had EVER been to winterhold......(wtf)

Answer (score 7):

If the horse was involved in a fight, it might be dead now.

Just fast travel to any point outside a city, stables for example; if your horse is alive you'll see him...

Answer (score 2):

What Tom said, if you fast-travel your horse (and any companion) will fast-travel with you and appear near you.  The one exception is if you fast travel into a city, then your horse goes to the stables outside the city.

Great way to pull that errant horse or housecarl who has decided to get trapped in geometry, can't stop fighting wolves, or gets pathed halfway around the world.

Answer (score -3):

Go to where you were arrested and it will be there

Comment: Try to give a little more detail with your answer.  A good answer is informative and well structured.

Comment: This answer is 6 years after the fact, which directly contradicts the question's edit with the answer.